# The first visible thumbnails in my tableview fail to appear - using LazyTableImages example as a base

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiimage, lazy-loading

I adapted the code from the LazyTableImages example on developer.apple.com and it all works except that it failed to load the images for the first 4 rows (there are 4 rows visible on load). When I scroll down and stop, the new rows' images are loaded correctly and when I scroll back up, the fist 4 images are also loaded correctly. So the problem is the initial loading.

I use fetch controller for loading the table data and it reads from a CoreData database. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I added an additional check like this:

```
if (self.screeningsTable.dragging == NO && 
    self.screeningsTable.decelerating == NO && movie.MovieID) {
  [self startImageDownload:movie forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

as to check if the row actually has a valid object yet. So in order to load the images of the first rows, I added `[self loadImagesForOnscreenRows]` after the data has been loaded from the database, but it doesn't work.

Can you tell where I should put the `[self loadImagesForOnscreenRows]` so the first images are correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the TableView reloadData method didn't reload fast enough, so when the `[self loadImagesForOnscreenRows]` started, the cells weren't there yet. So I replaced `[myTable reloadData];` with `[myTable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` which did the trick.
Hope that helps someone.